# SWIFT Looping Muliti-Level JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I need some help figuring this one out...

I'm trying to loop through a multi-level or multidimensional JSON object then save Key & Value Data.

With the below SWIFT code I'm getting the following error at the line where i call `saveAssessmentData()`: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x10ff76d68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10ff76fe8)`.

Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

```
func saveAssessmentData(testName: String, questionData: NSDictionary, sectionName: String){
// save to core data //
print("Saving Section: \(sectionName) for test: \(testName) QuestionData: \(questionData)")
}

let tests = "{\"testOne\":[{\"sectionOne\":[{\"questionOne\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I dont have one\"},\"questionTwo\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I still dont have one\"},\"questionThree\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"Third time is not the charm\"}]}],\"testTwo\":[{\"sectionOne\":[{\"questionOne\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I dont have one\"},\"questionTwo\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I still dont have one\"},\"questionThree\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"Third time is not the charm\"}]}],\"testThree\":[{\"sectionOne\":[{\"questionOne\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I dont have one\"},\"questionTwo\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"I still dont have one\"},\"questionThree\":\"for loops swift\",\"Answer\":\"Third time is not the charm\"}]}]}"

let JSONstring = tests.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONstring!, options:[]) as! NSDictionary

for (testName, testSections) in JSON{

    for (sectionName, questionData) in testSections as! NSDictionary{
        print("\(sectionName) has \(questionData.count) questions")

        saveAssessmentData(testName as! String, questionData: questionData as! NSDictionary, sectionName: sectionName as! String)
    }

}
```

Comment: The error message clearly says that you are trying to cast an `Array` to `Dictionary` which does not work. Read the JSON, `[]` represents an array, `{}`  represents a dictionary. PS: Don't use Foundation `NSArray` / `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types

Comment: Awesome Thanks! Please forgive my noobness!